# Proof based on Triangles

Tags: euclidean-geometry

for an acute triangle,prove that $a^2+b^2>c^2$

Well, I dropped a perpendicular from B to O but still I can't prove the question because I can't prove that $2a^2>2cz$

Where z is the side BO
Pls help me

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Now please help, it's for my Olympiad exam

Comment: You can prove it by using Cosine Rule.

Comment: Ohkay, but in the class they haven't taught cosine rule yet, though I know that, but guess the teacher wants us to prove with geometry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming angle **B** to be an acute angle.

[image]

Let $BL=x$,

Thus $AL^2=c^2-x^2=b^2-(a-x)^2 \implies c^2+a^2-b^2=2ax\implies c^2+a^2\geq b^2 $( as $2ax \geq 0$ )